# How to use single service in two controller in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, ng-controller

I have a indexpage as

```
<body ng-controller="MasterCtrl">
  <div id="page-wrapper" ng-class="{'open': toggle}" ng-cloak>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper" ng-controller="SidebarCtrl">
         <ul class="sidebar">
            <li>
                **<a href="#/nextpage?team={{department_name}}">Page Lik data <span class="menu-icon fa fa-road"></span></a>**
            </li>
         </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Main Content -->
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

The employee data we are getting form http://localhost:3000/employees?employee_id=764967674 is

```
[
{
location: "BLR",
department: "Core",
designation: "desig",
name: "Mr X",
gender: "M",
employee_id: 764967674,
email: "thisidas@example.com",
mobile: 7654578882,
_id: "5atsda5sdasd",
}
]
```

sidebar_ctrl:

```
/**
 * sidebar  Controller
 */

 angular.module('tool')
 .controller('SidebarCtrl', ['$scope', '$cookieStore', 'Employee', '$window', '$stateParams', '$log', SidebarCtrl]);

 function SidebarCtrl($scope, $cookieStore, Employee, $window, $stateParams, $log) {

    $scope.emp_id =  $stateParams.emp_id

    if($scope.emp_id) {
        var employee_Data = Employee.query({employee_id: $scope.emp_id}, function() {           
            $scope.department_name = employee_Data[0].department;
            alert("asd");   
        });
    }

}
```

employee service is

```
angular.module('PdbTool')
  .factory('Employee', ['$resource', Employee]);

  function Employee($resource) {  

       return $resource('localhost:3000/employees?', { employee_id: '@id' }, {
         query: {method:'GET', isArray: true},
 });
}
```

There is another ng-controller that is using the same service

```
/**
 * Profile  Controller
 */

 angular.module('PdbTool')
 .controller('ProfileCtrl', ['$scope', '$cookieStore', 'Employee', '$window', '$stateParams', '$log', ProfileCtrl]);

 function ProfileCtrl($scope, $cookieStore, Employee, $window, $stateParams, $log) {

    $scope.emp_id =  $stateParams.emp_id

    if($scope.emp_id) {
        var entries = Employee.query({employee_id: $scope.emp_id}, function() {             
            $scope.emp_name = entries[0].name;
            $scope.emp_department = entries[0].department;
            $scope.emp_location = entries[0].location;
            $scope.emp_designation = entries[0].designation;
            $scope.emp_email = entries[0].email;    
        });
    }

}
```

In the employee template html

```
<tr>
                                            <th>Designation</th>
                                            <td>{{emp_designation}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Department</th>
                                            <td>{{emp_department}}</td>
                                        </tr>
```

The values are population but in the sidebar

Page Lik data

data is not displaying ? for url redirection

Comment: Is your alert in alert("asd") getting called?

Comment: No .. but data is making the req ..

Comment: which controller you have bind for employee route? If Its only profileCtrl then to reflect data in another controller. You have broadcast an event.

Comment: not using callback of `$resource` properly, data is in the argument not the `var` you are creating